# Voltage produced in transformer

Tags: voltage

The voltage produced in the turns of the coil in a transformer is given by (Faradys law):

$$\epsilon\left(t\right)=\text{n}\times\phi'\left(t\right)\space\left[\text{V}\right]\tag1$$

Where $\text{n}$ is the number of turns of the coil and $\phi$ is the flux.

The Law of Hopkinson gives that the resistance of the coil equals:

$$\text{R}_{\text{cu}}=\frac{\text{L}_{\text{cu}}\times\rho}{\text{A}_{\text{cu}}}\space\left[\Omega\right]\tag2$$

And:

$$\phi\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{n}\times\text{I}\left(t\right)}{\text{R}_{\text{mag}}}\space\left[\text{Wb}\right]\tag3$$

For $\text{R}_{\text{mag}}$, we get:

$$\text{R}_{\text{mag}}=\frac{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}}{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}}\space\left[\Omega\right]\tag4$$

Combining all this from above:

$$\epsilon\left(t\right)=\text{n}\times\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left\{\frac{\text{n}\times\text{I}\left(t\right)}{\frac{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}}{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}}}\right\}=\text{n}^2\times\frac{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}}{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}}\times\text{I}'\left(t\right)\space\left[\text{V}\right]\tag5$$

For the input voltage we can write:

$$\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)\approx\epsilon\left(t\right)\space\left[\text{V}\right]\tag6$$

When the input voltage equals:

$$\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\space\left[\text{V}\right]\tag7$$

And for $\text{I}\left(t\right)$ we have, that that equals the current trough the resistor ($\text{R}_{\text{cu}}$) and the coil ($\text{L}_{\text{cu}}$).

So, for $\text{I}\left(t\right)$ we get:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=-\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}^2+\left(\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}\right)^2}}\sin\left(\omega t-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}}{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}}\right)\right)\space\left[\text{A}\right]\tag8$$

So in the end we can conclude:

$$\color{red}{\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\approx-\text{n}^2\times\frac{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}}{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}}\times\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\times\omega}{\sqrt{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}^2+\left(\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}\right)^2}}\times\cos\left(\omega t-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}}{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}}\right)\right)}$$

Calculating the RMS of both sides:

$$\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{2}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times\text{n}^2\times\frac{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}}{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}}\times\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\times\omega}{\sqrt{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}^2+\left(\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}\right)^2}}\tag9$$

Which gives:

$$\text{n}^2\approx\frac{\text{L}_{\text{fe}}\times\sqrt{\text{R}_{\text{cu}}^2+\left(\omega\times\text{L}_{\text{cu}}\right)^2}}{\mu_0\times\mu_r\times\text{A}_{\text{fe}}\times\omega}\tag{10}$$

> Question: Am I right about all the formula's I stated above?

**IMPORTANT:**

$\text{L}_{\text{fe}}$ and $\text{L}_{\text{cu}}$ are length so in meter

Comment: Is there anything which makes you doubt that you are right?

Comment: @user1583209 Well, my book makes a few assumptions but I don't want to do that and I want to look at the difference between using the assumptions and not, but I don't know if what I am doing is correct....

Comment: I don't think what you have here is Hopkinson's law. It is just the formula for the resistance of a wire. Could you specify to which parts of the transformer your indices (Cu, fe, r, mag, in) belong? Also you seem to have the same n in both parts of the transformer. Is this intentional?

Comment: @user1583209 I'm talking about the primary side of the transformer. Look to my edit